# Judging Linux process memory with top

Tags: linux, memory, memory-leaks, nginx

I'm trying to understand whether a long running process (nginx) is leaking memory.  I'm trying to figure out fancy tools like Valgrind, but meanwhile I'm just using top.

I run my process and fire up a script to endlessly send requests to the process.  I let that soak for a few hours.

I see this line in top:

```
  PID USER       PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND 
20209 tigerfoot  20   0 56380 3376 2260 S  4.0  0.1   7:23.14 nginx
```

The cpu measure drifts around very slightly but everything else, particularly the memory, holds solid.

But at the top of the top output I see this:

```
Mem:   3717188k total,  1516752k used,  2200436k free,   151368k buffers
```

Over the hours the free memory has slowly but steadily been decreasing.  Of course this is a Linux box with other software running (e.g. Mongo), but all these other systems should be basically resting.

Should I take comfort that over time my nginx is not leaking because its process memory is solid, or should I worry about the slow leak in overall system memory?  In other words is it possible for my process memory stats to be stable but still be leaking memory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Over the time linux caches free memory.And that frees up whenever a requirement comes.
free -g shows the real picture.
in +-buffers section u can see used memory which is the real used memory and not the cached one.If that is stable , your process should be fine.